# jQuery won't act on a partial rendered through AJAX in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, dom, ujs

My app has something called "memos". And you can reply to other memos using @ tags inside your memo. For example:

> Hi this is a reply to @123

Then, if you click, @123, then memo #123 is rendered underneath the memo you're viewing.

**_memo.html.erb:**

```
<div class="memo">
    <div class="memo-content">
        <%= raw simple_format(memo.content).gsub(/@([a-z0-9A-Z]+)/, '<a  data-remote="true" class="marker" href="/memos/\1">@\1</a>')%>
    </div>
</div>
```

**app/assets/javascripts/memo.js:**

```
$(function() {
    $(".marker").on("ajax:success", function(e, content){
        console.log("hi")
        $(".memos-container").append(content);
    });
})
```

**memos_controller.rb:**

```
  def show
    @memo = Memo.find(params[:id])
    if request.xhr?
      render partial: "shared/memo", locals: { memo: @memo } 
    end
  end
```

The first click works fine. If I click on `@123`, then memo #123 is rendered in the page. If I click on any other @ tags inside that first memo, they all work too.

Problem is, nothing inside that rendered memo is clickable. So if memo #123 also has an @456 tag, and I click on it, nothing is rendered.

Looking at my Network console in Chrome, it *is* making the `get` request, only the jQuery is not acting on those newly rendered DOM elements.

I've looked at similar questions on SO, and they all say use `.on`, which, as far as I can tell is what I'm doing. But I'm a total Javascript newb.

Comment: Where is your `click` handler? Specifically, do you use `.click(...)`, or do you use `.on('click'...)`?

Comment: @Amadan That's all the code. It's on success of the Ajax request: http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/

Comment: Doh, I missed `data-remote`...

Comment: @Amadan doh myself, I should've read the docs better because I got it to work after re-reading that (posted an answer below). But if there's a better way to do this I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by using this:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).ajaxSuccess(function(e, content){
        console.log(content.responseText)
        $(".memos-container").append(content.responseText);
    });
})
```

But if there's a better way to do this I'm open to suggestions :)

Now turbolinks is making it act all wonky. But That's a different topic...